# Media uploader not saving when options change in Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, media, save, uploader

I'm having a problem with my custom options page in Wordpress. The issue concerns the media uploader I have put a while ago. It works properly, but when re-saving options the url in the field, where the file was uploaded, disappears and no image is displayed in my html code. This happens just when I save options two consecutive times in the same options page. The url should remain in the field, but this does not happen.

The code of the media uploader to put in `functions.php` is:

```
//Media Uploader Scripts
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
wp_register_script('my-upload', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/uploader.js', array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox'));
wp_enqueue_script('my-upload');

//Media Uploader Style
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');

if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'my_plugin_page') {
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'my_admin_styles');
}
```

Where the content of the `uploader.js` is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#upload_image_button').click(function() {
formfield = jQuery('#upload_image').attr('name');
tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
return false;
});

window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
 imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
 jQuery('#upload_image').val(imgurl);
 tb_remove();
}

});
```

And this was the code added to `functions.php`

```
<?php

add_action( 'init', 'th_admin_init' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'th_options_page_init' );

function th_admin_init() {
    $options = get_option( "th_theme_options" );
    if ( empty( $options ) ) {
        $options = array(
            'th_intro' => 'Some intro text for the home page',
            'th_tag_class' => false,
            'th_ga' => false,
            'upload_image' => ''
        );
        add_option( "th_theme_options", $options, '', 'yes' );
    }   
}

function th_options_page_init() {
    $theme_data = get_theme_data( TEMPLATEPATH . '/style.css' );
    $options_page = add_theme_page( $theme_data['Name']. ' Theme options', $theme_data['Name']. ' Opzioni', 'edit_theme_options', 'theme-options', 'th_options_page' );
    add_action( "load-{$options_page}", 'th_load_options_page' );
}

function th_load_options_page() {
    if ( $_POST["th-options-submit"] == 'Y' ) {
        check_admin_referer( "th-options-page" );
        th_save_theme_options();
        $url_parameters = isset($_GET['tab'])? 'updated=true&tab='.$_GET['tab'] : 'updated=true';
        wp_redirect(admin_url('themes.php?page=theme-options&'.$url_parameters));
        exit;
    }
}

function th_save_theme_options() {
    global $pagenow;
    $options = get_option( "th_theme_options" );

    if ( $pagenow == 'themes.php' && $_GET['page'] == 'theme-options' ){ 
        if ( isset ( $_GET['tab'] ) )
            $tab = $_GET['tab']; 
        else
            $tab = 'homepage'; 

        switch ( $tab ){ 
            case 'general' :
                $options['th_tag_class']      = $_POST['th_tag_class'];
            break; 
            case 'footer' : 
                $options['th_ga']  = $_POST['th_ga'];
            break;
            case 'homepage' : 
                $options['th_intro']      = $_POST['th_intro'];
                $options['upload_image']      = $_POST['upload_image'];
            break;
        }
    }

    if( !current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' ) ){
        if ( $options['th_ga']  )
            $options['th_ga'] = stripslashes( esc_textarea( wp_filter_post_kses( $options['th_ga'] ) ) );
        if ( $options['th_intro'] )
            $options['th_intro'] = stripslashes( esc_textarea( wp_filter_post_kses( $options['th_intro'] ) ) );
        if ( $options['upload_image']  )
            $options['upload_image'] = stripslashes( esc_textarea( wp_filter_post_kses( $options['upload_image'] ) ) );
    }

    $updated = update_option( "th_theme_options", $options );
}

function th_admin_tabs( $current = 'homepage' ) { 
    $tabs = array( 'homepage' => 'Home', 'general' => 'Generali', 'footer' => 'Footer' ); 
    $links = array();
    echo '<div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"><br></div>';
    echo '<h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">';
    foreach( $tabs as $tab => $name ){
        $class = ( $tab == $current ) ? ' nav-tab-active' : '';
        echo "<a class='nav-tab$class' href='?page=theme-options&tab=$tab'>$name</a>";

    }
    echo '</h2>';
}

function th_options_page() {
    global $pagenow;
    $options = get_option( "th_theme_options" );
    $theme_data = get_theme_data( TEMPLATEPATH . '/style.css' );

//Media Uploader Scripts
wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
wp_register_script('my-upload', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/js/uploader.js', array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox'));
wp_enqueue_script('my-upload');

//Media Uploader Style
wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');

if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'theme_options') {
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_admin_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'my_admin_styles');
}

    ?>

<div class="wrap">
        <h2><?php echo $theme_data['Name']; ?> Opzioni</h2>

        <?php
            if ( 'true' == esc_attr( $_GET['updated'] ) ) echo '<div class="updated" ><p>Modifiche salvate.</p></div>';

            if ( isset ( $_GET['tab'] ) ) th_admin_tabs($_GET['tab']); else th_admin_tabs('homepage');
        ?>

        <div id="poststuff">
            <form method="post" action="<?php admin_url( 'themes.php?page=theme-options' ); ?>">
                <?php
                wp_nonce_field( "th-options-page" ); 

                if ( $pagenow == 'themes.php' && $_GET['page'] == 'theme-options' ){ 

                    if ( isset ( $_GET['tab'] ) ) $tab = $_GET['tab']; 
                    else $tab = 'homepage'; 

                    echo '<table class="form-table">';
                    switch ( $tab ){
                        case 'general' :
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="th_tag_class">Tags with CSS classes:</label></th>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="th_tag_class" name="th_tag_class" type="checkbox" <?php if ( $options["th_tag_class"] ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="true" /> 
                                    <span class="description">Output each post tag with a specific CSS class using its slug.</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        break; 
                        case 'footer' : 
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="th_ga">Insert tracking code:</label></th>
                                <td>
                                    <textarea id="th_ga" name="th_ga" cols="60" rows="5"><?php echo esc_html( stripslashes( $options["th_ga"] ) ); ?></textarea><br/>
                                    <span class="description">Enter your Google Analytics tracking code:</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        break;
                        case 'homepage' : 
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <th><label for="th_intro">Introduction</label></th>
                                <td>
                                    <textarea id="th_intro" name="th_intro" cols="60" rows="5" ><?php echo esc_html( stripslashes( $options["th_intro"] ) ); ?></textarea><br/>
                                    <span class="description">Enter the introductory text for the home page:</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <th><label for="upload_image">Upload Image</label></th>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="upload_image" value="" />
                                    <input id="upload_image_button" type="button" class="button-secondary" value="Carica Immagine" />
                                <br /><span class="description">Enter an URL or upload an image for the banner.</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <?php
                        break;
                    }
                    echo '</table>';
                }
                ?>
                <p class="submit" style="clear: both;">
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit"  class="button-primary" value="Update options" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="th-options-submit" value="Y" />
                </p>
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>
<?php
}


?>
```

Anyone can help me?

Thank you in advance!

**------------ SOLUTION ------------**

It was not a DB problem. It was just an HTML problem, because the `value` element inside the input named `upload_image` was setted on `""`. So change the code, inside the form in the `function.php` file, from:

```
<input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="upload_image" value="" />
```

to:

```
<input id="upload_image" type="text" size="36" name="upload_image" value="<?php echo esc_html( stripslashes( $options["upload_image"] ) ); ?>" />
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the custom options page.

Comment: Code of the custom options page added!

Comment: did you check and see what happens in the database? after you save the options both once and then again consecutively

Comment: It's strange because I don't find any field in the db where is inserted the media url. I have also tried to check the file `wp-admin/options.php` but nothing, I didn't find the url of the media.

Comment: it should be in your options table under the option key/name `th_theme_options` it should be an array..

Comment: No `th_theme_options` found. [Just these tuples under option name](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/4299/11755766.jpg)

Comment: Then `add_option( "th_theme_options", $options, '', 'yes' );` doesnt work because that part stores your data in the options table in the db have you tried `update_option( "th_theme_options", $options, '', 'yes' );` instead

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work.. The same problem occurs, the url it's not saved after the first update.

Comment: yeah but if dont have values in the database thats the reason why your not able to retrieve and anything and then you are overwriting your data with blank so you cant see nothing in the DB.

Comment: I have finally found that `th_theme_options` thing, and all in the DB worked properly. So it was not a DB problem. But I have a good news: I've found the solution. It was just an HTML problem, because the `value` element inside the input named `upload_image` was setted on `""`. Every time I updated it gave me back a blank field because the media url was not memorized in the `value=""` of the input element. Now I just put inside `value=""` the code `<?php echo esc_html( stripslashes( $options["upload_image"] ) ); ?>` that retrieves the media url. Thank you so much for all your help, really :)